# Application of wget to "Save As Complete Web Page"

Tags: dynamic, html, wget, save-as

Is there a way to wget-ing a web page and obtaining the same exact result (that is a .htm file) as with the browser command "Save As Complete Web Page" (Chrome or Firefox)?

I was not able to find any configuration of wget that does it correctly. I'm interesting in saving automatically dynamic data.
The web page is the following:

http://football.bettor.com/barclays-premier-league-winner-2011-12-betting-odds/2011-11-19/market/652852

Now, I've automatized the Save As browser command through java mouse/keyboard control, but it is strongly inefficient and produces crashes after a 30/40 minutes.

Comment: do you want the saved page to render correctly, as the original does? Or do you only care about the textual content of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ wget --verbose --page-requisites --convert-links --adjust-extension --force-directories \
  http://football.bettor.com/barclays-premier-league-winner-2011-12-betting-odds/2011-11-19/market/652852
```